# React redux + fetch data from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-redux

While I am trying to fetch user data from firebase in my user reducer like this :

```
const initialState = {
    user : {
        firstname : "",
        lastname : "",
        todoList : [],
        addressBook : []
    }
};

const usersReducer = async (state = initialState, action) => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    switch(action.type) {

        case FETCH_USER_DATA:
            const docRef = doc(db, "users", action.payload.userUid);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
            if (docSnap.exists()) {
              console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
            } else {
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
            return {
                user: {firstname: docSnap.data().firstname, lastname: docSnap.data().lastname, todoList: [], addressBook: []}
            }
        
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

When I get my user state in my components I receive this object :

> {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 1, "_z": {"user": {"addressBook": [Array], "firstname": "XXX", "lastname": "XXX", "todoList": [Array]}}}

I dont' understand why I get this attribute in my object: `"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 1, "_z":`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
const ref = db
  .collection('users')
  .doc(action.payload.userUid)

const doc = await ref.get();

if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('Not exists');
} else {
  console.log('data', doc.data())
}
```